# Recording live Audio Streams on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, audio, xamarin, streaming

```
//Declare string for application temp path and tack on the file extension
string fileName = string.Format ("Myfile{0}.wav", DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
string audioFilePath = Path.Combine (Path.GetTempPath (), fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Audio File Path: " + audioFilePath);

url = NSUrl.FromFilename(audioFilePath);
//set up the NSObject Array of values that will be combined with the keys to make the NSDictionary
NSObject[] values = new NSObject[]
{
    NSNumber.FromFloat (44100.0f), //Sample Rate
    NSNumber.FromInt32 ((int)AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.LinearPCM), //AVFormat
    NSNumber.FromInt32 (2), //Channels
    NSNumber.FromInt32 (16), //PCMBitDepth
    NSNumber.FromBoolean (false), //IsBigEndianKey
    NSNumber.FromBoolean (false) //IsFloatKey
};

//Set up the NSObject Array of keys that will be combined with the values to make the NSDictionary
NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[]
{
    AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey
};

//Set Settings with the Values and Keys to create the NSDictionary
settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (values, keys);

//Set recorder parameters
recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(url, new AudioSettings(settings), out error);

//Set Recorder to Prepare To Record
recorder.PrepareToRecord();
```

[This](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/record_sound/) code works well, but how can you keep a record from a microphone directly to stream?
I did not find any information in the Internet, i hope you can help me

Comment: Can you please share your code???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for buffered access to the audio stream (recording or playback), iOS provides it via `Audio Queue Services` (`AVAudioRecorder` is too high level), so then as audio buffers are filled, iOS calls your `callback` with a filled buffer from the queue, you do something with it (save it to disk, write it to a C#-based Stream, send to a playback audio queue [speakers], etc...) and, normally, place it back into the queue for reuse.

Something like this starts recording to `queue` of audio buffers:

```
var recordFormat = new AudioStreamBasicDescription() {
    SampleRate = 8000,
    Format = AudioFormatType.LinearPCM,
    FormatFlags = AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsSignedInteger | AudioFormatFlags.LinearPCMIsPacked,
    FramesPerPacket = 1,
    ChannelsPerFrame = 1,
    BitsPerChannel = 16,
    BytesPerPacket = 2,
    BytesPerFrame = 2,
    Reserved = 0
};

recorder = new InputAudioQueue (recordFormat);

for (int count = 0; count < BufferCount; count++) {
    IntPtr bufferPointer;
    recorder.AllocateBuffer(AudioBufferSize, out bufferPointer);
    recorder.EnqueueBuffer(bufferPointer, AudioBufferSize, null);
}
recorder.InputCompleted += HandleInputCompleted;
recorder.Start ();
```

So assuming a `AudioBufferSize` of 8k and a `BufferCount` of 3 in this example, so once the first of three buffers is filled, our handler `HandleInputCompleted` is called (since there are 2 buffers still in the `queue` recording continues to them.

Our `InputCompleted` handler:

```
private void HandleInputCompleted (object sender, InputCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // We received a new buffer of audio, do something with it....

    // Some unsafe code will be required to rip the buffer...

    // Place the buffer back into the queue so iOS knows you are done with it
    recorder.EnqueueBuffer(e.IntPtrBuffer, AudioBufferSize, null);

    // At some point you need to call `recorder.Stop();`  ;-)
}
```

(I ripped out our code from the handler as it is a custom audio-2-text learning neutral network as we use really small buffers in a very large queue to reduce feedback latency and load that audio data within single TCP/UDP packets for cloud processing (think `Siri` ;-)

In this handler you have access to the `Pointer` to the buffer that is currently filled via `InputCompletedEventArgs.IntPtrBuffer`, Using that pointer you could `peek` each byte in the buffer and `poke` them to your C#-based Stream if that is your goal.

#### Apple has a great tech article concerning Audio Queue: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AboutAudioQueues/AboutAudioQueues.html

Comment: thank for you answer. Xamarin did not found AudioStreamBasicDescription and i tried include "using Monotouch.AudioToolbox;" not found too.

Comment: @user6196834 `using AudioToolbox;` will get you the proper namespace

Comment: Thanks! You are the best!

Comment: Thanks, can you please give the code in handler completed in c# of how to read it and play it when needed??? I tried but not working

Comment: @Manthan Post a *new* question with the code that is not working.

Comment: I successfully received the response continuously in the handler completed but the now How to read the dara from audioqueuebuffer and audioqueuerefbuffer? I want to convert it to byte and pass it. Thanks